# Where to obtain JavaFx Authoring tool?

Tags: java, javafx, frontend, rich-internet-application

Where can I get the JavaFx Authoring tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now there only was a demonstration of the authoring tool at the JavaOne Conference last month. Release date is supposed to be end of this year!

You can watch the presentation in the videos at this [blog](http://sellmic.com/blog/2009/06/05/javafx-authoring-tool-demo-at-javaone-2009-with-video/).

So you have to wait for the next javafx release.

In the meantime you have to use what netbeans offers (or the eclipse plugin, which isn't yet very convincing as I thnik) together with the production suite from javafx 1.2 - which helps you to import graphics from adobe illustrator or photoshop into your javafx apps.